# I want a selected value in a combobox on form1, to be automatically populated into a textbox/label on form 3

Tags: vb.net, forms, user-interface, combobox, textbox

I have 3 forms at the moment, form 1 you select 4 peices of data,
Form 2 you select up to 10.

I want it so when you go to form 3, all selected fields on form 2 are shown on the 3rd form.... as uneditable text fields (labels i guess)

I would attach some diagrams to make this 5000x easier to explain, but i cant yet.

I just need to know how i can make the code grab the values input into combobox's and textbox's and output them on form 3.

Edit;
i have no code in place as i have been trying differnt techniques and have gotten nowhere

```
 Me.ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    Me.ComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"ClaimCode", "PostCode", "AlgPremium", "Etc", "Etc", "Etc"})
    Me.ComboBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(27, 33)
    Me.ComboBox1.Name = "ComboBox1"
    Me.ComboBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(225, 21)
    Me.ComboBox1.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'ComboBox2
    '
    Me.ComboBox2.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    Me.ComboBox2.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.ComboBox2.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Single", "Multi"})
    Me.ComboBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(275, 33)
    Me.ComboBox2.Name = "ComboBox2"
    Me.ComboBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(147, 21)
    Me.ComboBox2.TabIndex = 3
    '
    'Values
    '
    Me.Values.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(450, 34)
    Me.Values.Name = "Values"
    Me.Values.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(297, 20)
    Me.Values.TabIndex = 4
```

I want the above values (from FORM2) when selected, taking out and putting into the following fields on FORM3...

```
 'TextBox1
    '
    Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(11, 13)
    Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
    Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(259, 20)
    Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'TextBox2
    '
    Me.TextBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(9, 13)
    Me.TextBox2.Name = "TextBox2"
    Me.TextBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 20)
    Me.TextBox2.TabIndex = 1
```

Nothing is named yet as i just need to understand how to do this, there will be alot more done with the data than just passed into the form, but for now. this will grant me basic understanding i work from.

For a full description, i will have Various Templates of XML, when you select the 4 values on FORM1, a specific template will be picked in the background.
Then in FORM2 you will select values you wish to modify on this template, these will be modified on the XML and the XML posted to a Test harness where various filters/rules will be ran against it (drools),
Then on form3 a list of all Fields you changed on form2, the values you input on FORM2 and how they came back out after the morphs/filters in the Test harness will be displayed and the XML produced will be saved and linked to via FORM3.

I am a Lonnngggg way from having the program at this stage, but i am just trying to understand how to use the GUI and how to pass data from one form to another. or export it to an XML file

Comment: If you add some of the code you're actually trying it would be somewhat easier for us to help you.

Comment: From where in the code are the three forms being shown?  Does each form show the next one in consecutive fashion, or is there some controlling object which shows all three?  Are the forms always shown in the same order, or are they ever displayed out of order or at the same time?

Comment: Yes, form 1 "Next button" makes form 2 pop up ontop (Form2.showdialog) and the same from Form2 to Form3
Only ever shown one after the other, Hopefully my edit to my post may clear this up a little bit.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend simply adding public properties to the forms that can be set to the needed values before `ShowDialog` is called.  Then, when the form loads, it can default it's controls to the values in those properties.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, Im new to VB, usually work in Java(drools/Tiny bit of Swing)
Could you provide an example, or a link to one if you know of any. That i can work from. I tried the public properties technique, but i was a little lost and couldn't get it to work (had no idea what went where)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data to a form by setting public properties before displaying it, like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As New FormVb2()
        f.TextBox1Value = TextBox1.Text
        f.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then you can use the value in the public property when the form loads, like this:

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Property TextBox1Value As String

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1Value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much, took me a some playing around, but passing data threw now. 
Thanks alot Steven!

Comment: @Jonathan Spickernell if Steven's help worked, why won't you accept his answer?

Comment: Because i had no idea how to! i tried to vote it up, but it said i needed 15rep, so left it at that!
Accepted it now. Thanks again Steven

Comment: No problem :) You need a certain number of reputation points before you can vote up answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

val is global variable

```
Dim Val as string=string.empty



Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        val = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    End Sub



  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xfrm As New Form3
        xfrm.TextBox1.Text = val 
        xfrm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Globals are almost always a bad idea.  If you had a gun to my head, you may even get me to confess that they are *always* a bad idea, but I usually try to avoid being *that* emphatic.